# SaveHTML is empty when constructing a new <picture> tag in PHP DomDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm knocking together a wordpress plugin to convert legacy `<img...>` tags to `<picture>...<source...>` tags for use with webp.

Rather than start regex'ing and sticking strings together, I figured PHP's DOMDocument would be a more elegant solution.

But, on constructing, what I think looks like valid markup using the below, the DOM object created appears empty, as does the HTML generated by `SaveHTML`.

Here's my code...

```
  $new_dom = new DOMDocument();
  $picture = $new_dom->createElement('picture');
  $picture = $new_dom->appendChild($picture);

  $source_webp = $new_dom->createElement('source');
  $source_webp->setAttribute('srcset',$srcset_webp);
  $source_webp->setAttribute('sizes', $sizes);

  $picture->appendChild($source_webp);

  $source_jpg = $new_dom->createElement('source');
  $source_jpg->setAttribute('srcset',$srcset);
  $source_jpg->setAttribute('sizes', $sizes);

  $picture->appendChild($source_jpg);

  $str=$new_dom->saveHTML();
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Without knowing the parameters of the various input variables it is hard to test to replicate the issue you are facing. I tested this with "mickey mouse" variables and the generated HTML looks valid. Please add suitable values/variables that would permit testing by others

Comment: Spot on, stray whitespace was confusing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, stray whitespace was causing the issue. And now we have valid HTML output. Phew.